# Batch file "start" command and parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

Right now I have a batch file launching a shortcut which works fine, but i want to directly launch the program with the parameters from the batch file rather than it firing up a shortcut.

The shortcut contains this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe" !LoadLayout "White"
```

I don't know how to add the parameters using the `start` command.

Right now this is what the batch file looks like:

```
@echo off
start "" /b "C:\Users\Doss\Documents\Rainmeter\White Layout.lnk"
```

Comment: (This question has absolutely nothing to do with DOS, by the way.)

Comment: Your parameters are specified it the shortcut. You aren't adding any parameters from the start command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's something unusual going on, this should work perfectly well:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe" !LoadLayout "White"
```